# Setting pandas multiple rows with enlargement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

According to the `pandas` documentation, it should be possible to append-non-existent rows a `DataFrame` using [setting with enlargment](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement), but while *retrieving* multiple missing keys works fine, *setting* multiple missing keys throws a `KeyError`:

```
import pandas as pd

print(pd.__version__)     # '0.19.2'

df = pd.DataFrame([[9] * 3] * 3, index=list('ABC'))

## Show a mix of extant and missing keys:
inds_e = pd.Index(list('BCDE'))
print(df.loc[inds_e])
#      0    1    2
# B  9.0  9.0  9.0
# C  9.0  9.0  9.0
# D  NaN  NaN  NaN
# E  NaN  NaN  NaN

## Assign the enlarging subset to -1:
try:
    df.loc[inds_e] = -1
except KeyError as e:
    print(e)
    # "Index(['D', 'E'], dtype='object') not in index"
```

Setting multiple existent keys works just fine, and setting any one row with enlargment works fine as well:

```
## Assign all the non-missing keys at once:
inds_nm = inds_e.intersection(df.index)
df.loc[inds_nm] = -1

## Assign the missing keys one at a time:
inds_m = inds_e.difference(df.index)
for ind in inds_m:
    df.loc[ind] = -1

print(df)
#    0  1  2
# A  9  9  9
# B -1 -1 -1
# C -1 -1 -1
# D -1 -1 -1
# E -1 -1 -1
```

That said, this seems horribly inelegant and inefficient. There is a [very similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319888/setting-dataframe-values-with-enlargement), but that was solved using the `combine_first()` functionality - both [`combine_first()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) and [`update()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) methods don't seem to have the same semantics as a simple assignment - in the case of `combine_first`, non-null values are not updated, and in the case of `update`, null values in the righthand side dataframe will not overwrite non-null values in the lefthand side.

Is this a bug in `pandas`, and if not, what is the "proper" way to assign values to a mixture of extant and missing keys with enlargment on a `pandas` dataframe?

**Edit**: Looks like [there is an issue about this from 2014](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7887) on the `pandas` github. The de-facto is apparently to use `df.reindex`, but it's not clear to me how that works when you're trying to assign a subset of all keys with enlargement.

Comment: FYI - as of Pandas 0.21.0, indexing with missing labels is officially [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-with-list-with-missing-labels-is-deprecated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your edit, you can assign with overlap and enlargement by using [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex) on the union of your two indexes, followed by `loc`:

```
# Reindex to add the missing indicies (fill_value preserves integer dtype).
df = df.reindex(df.index.union(inds_e), fill_value=-1)

# Perform the assignment.
df.loc[inds_e] = -1
```

It seems like this does a bit extra assignments here, as the `loc` will double fill some of the values that `fill_value` takes care of.  A couple simple timings seem to show that it's faster to double fill than just determining the left over locations to fill.  You don't necessarily need to use `fill_value` either; I just used it in this case to preserve dtype.  If you have floats instead of integers it is completely unnecessary.

The resulting output:

```
   0  1  2
A  9  9  9
B -1 -1 -1
C -1 -1 -1
D -1 -1 -1
E -1 -1 -1
```

**Timings**

This does appear to be fairly efficient.  Using the following setup to produce a larger example:

```
n = 10**5
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000, size=(n, 4)))
inds = pd.Index(range(n//2, 3*n//2))

def root(df, inds):
    df = df.reindex(df.index.union(inds), fill_value=-1)
    df.loc[inds] = -1
    return df

def paul(df, inds):
    ## Assign all the non-missing keys at once:
    inds_nm = inds.intersection(df.index)
    df.loc[inds_nm] = -1

    ## Assign the missing keys one at a time:
    inds_m = inds.difference(df.index)
    for ind in inds_m:
        df.loc[ind] = -1

    return df
```

I get the following timing:

```
%timeit root(df.copy(), inds)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.5 ms per loop
```

I couldn't get your solution to run with `n=10**5`.  Using `n=10**4`:

```
%timeit paul(df.copy(), inds)
1 loop, best of 3: 14.1 s per loop
```

Comment: Yes, this is essentially what I ended up doing. Was hoping for a single action that does both, but given the comments in the Issue, this seems to be the right thing to do.